# Changing URLs after deploying Flask app

Tags: python, flask, url-routing

So, I have a flask application that works well when it's not deployed. Imagine it has pages for `/index/` and `/home/` and `/home/field/`. Now that I have deployed the app using Apache and mod_wsgi, it needs to have a prefix for every URL.

Now, it should look like `/newapp/index/` and `/newapp/home/` and `/newapp/home/field/`.

So, I changed all of the URLs to include the new `/newapp/` prefix, but the only URL that works with it is the original `/index/` URL. All of the others return a

`Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server.`

in the browser when I click for that URL. I definitely handle that route in my `main.py`, so I don't know why it would not be found.

Anyone know what is going on?

---

**EDIT**: adding some code

Basically I changed all my code in `main.py` from:

**Original**:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    #Stuff    

@app.route('/home/')
def farms():
    #More stuff

@app.route('/home/<selector>')
def fields(selector):
    #Further stuff
```

To....

**New Code**

```
@app.route('/newapp/')
@app.route('/newapp/index/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    #Stuff    

@app.route('/newapp/home/')
def farms():
    #More stuff

@app.route('/newapp/home/<selector>')
def fields(selector):
    #Further stuff
```

I did this because the domain I am using already has another Flask app, so I had to differentiate between the two. Also, I expect there to be more flask apps in the future, so this `newapp` will end up being an identifier for any given flask app.

I changed main.py as well has all of my `href`s in my templates. So, the `href`s went from

```
href=/index/
```

to

```
href=/newapp/index/
```

And, I get the error that I posted above whenever I try to click on a link

---

**Further info**:

So, checking out the apache error logs one error says, `File does not exist: /var/www/flask_util.js,` because in my `main.py` I call `from flask_util_js import FlaskUtilJs`. I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the URL routing, but it might

Comment: can you share the code for main.py ? It is difficult to try and understand the issue without any code

Comment: Agreed, I've posted some code above

Comment: did you restart Apache server after making the code changes ?

Comment: Yes, definitely restarted Apache

Comment: For debugging purposes try to request your pages directly with a external tool. This way you easily tell if its a error on the backend or in your HTML page.  
For Mozilla you can use HttpRequester but there are similar Solutions for different Browsers

The js errors sounds more like your HTML page tries to load the js file but doesn't find it on the server. This might be an issue later but shouldn't cause the NotFound errors you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add the prefix in your code.

Say you have code like

```
@app.route('/hi', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def myIndex():
    return "Hello World!", 200
```

And you set your alias like to deploy it to www.myserver.com/app/

```
WSGIScriptAlias /app /var/www/myDir/myApp/app.wsgi
```

the server should automatically map www.myserver.com/app/hi to /hi in your application.

However if you set the mapping to

```
@app.route('/newapp/hi', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def myIndex():
    return "Hello World!", 200
```

You WSGI app would only receive the call for /hi (server strips away the prefix) so it would find no matching Path and return not found.

Comment: Trying it now. Will I have to change my `href`s? Like, will they be `href=/newapp/hi` or `href=/hi`

Comment: Hrefs should still be href="/newapp/hi"

Comment: Also try requesting the path directly either with a tool or the browser (enter www.example.com/newapp/hi) then its easy to see if its a error in the HTML or on the server side.

Comment: So now the page I get says `Internal Server Error` which corresponds to that JS python file import issue. Does that mean that the current problem is resolved?

Comment: Should be yes. Internal Server Error usually indicates the server tried to run your Endpoint function and it failed with a Exception/Timeout.

Comment: You should get the error/exception message in the apache logs. Check out http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques for more info about debugging with wsgi.